# Python Lookup values from another excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe D1 in Python .

```
Card No 
447430
363314
310629
```

I have another dataframe D2 which is lookup .

```
BadgeNumber FirstName   LastName    EmployeeNumber
447430  Rishipal    .   379362
363314  Forest Electric 1   233444
310629  Creative Office 1   213423
```

I have to modify the dataframe D1 as below . The Employee No. in the modified dataframe D1 comes from the  dataframe D2 . The Card no from D1 is matched against BadgeNumber in D2 and the corresponding EmployeeNumber is copied into D1 . Any pointers using Python and Pandas will be helpful .

```
Card No     Employee No.
447430  379362
363314  233444
310629  213423
```

Comment: Just a quick something to get you on your way.  Have a look at the `join()` function of a Pandas DataFrame.  This is similar to an SQL join in that you can specify `inner`, `outer` and on which column to join.  Have a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pandas.merge(D1, D2, how='left', left_on=['Card No'], right_on=['BadgeNumber'])
```